# How can I get my graphics lines to match up properly on Winforms picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, line, picturebox

I am trying to create a program where an image is processed (the details of that are irrelevant to this question, I think), and then the user can modify / "fine tune" the image by drawing lines wherever they may be needed.  For the sake of accuracy, I want the line to go from the point of one mouse click to the next.  I found a previously asked / answered question on Stack Overflow that seemed to provide a good template for me; here's my code:

```
private void imgPicture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (draw) {
            if (p1.X == 0) {
                p1.X = e.X;
                p1.Y = e.Y;
            }
            else {
                p2.X = e.X;
                p2.Y = e.Y;

                p1List.Add(p1);
                p2List.Add(p2);

                imgPicture.Invalidate();
                p1.X = 0;
            }
            Graphics pictureGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(imgPicture.Image);
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4)) {
                for (int x = 0; x < p1List.Count; x++) {
                    pictureGraphic.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the location where my clicks are registering are way off.  Here is a snip of my program; the blue line is about where I was TRYING to create the line, the red line is where it actually showed up.
[image: program image capture]

It seems like the further I get from the top left corner of the screen, the farther off the capture is.

Also, while I'm asking questions, does anyone know how I can permanently dispose of all the drawn lines that are created?  So that I can click a button and all the lines disappear?

Thanks for your help!  Stackoverflow is a life saver!

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it at the minute, its possible due to scaling and the fact you are trying to do a 1:1 mapping from mouseXY to pixelXY location. As to your second question you need to either just retain the original image to revert back to or keep a list of your lines and draw them from the list rather directly from when creating the line

Comment: Set the PictureBox.SizeMode property to Normal, high odds that it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sayse and Hans Passant it's working great now!  As Hans pointed out, I set the SizeMode property to Normal for the duration of the drawing function, then set it back to zoom when I was done, and it works great!

For the cleanup, all I had to do was use the Clear function on my two pointer lists, and the Dispose function on my Graphic.